# Getting a aws credentials error when I run user data of ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a shell script in my ec2 instance which has the following commands

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
aws s3 sync s3://fbt-pano-input /home/ubuntu/pano/Zip
python3 pano.py
```

When i run this shell script from the instance directly , it executes properly. However my instance user data is supposed to run this shell script. When it tries running it, it gives the following error
fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

It seems to be unable to run the sync command to download items from the bucket. Do i need to give a special access? It seemed to be working fine a few hours ago. Now all of a sudden it is not finding the credentials.

This is my user data code

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh

cd /home/ubuntu
sh ./panorama.sh
```

My aws config has the right credntials. why is it giving the error

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hard code AWS credentials in your instance. The AWS permissions that your EC2 application requires should be provided through **instance role**:

- [Using an IAM role to grant permissions to applications running on Amazon EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

Nevertheless, your user data executes under **root**, so your application will look for the credentials in the root home folder, not regular ubuntu user. To run your commands under different user, you can try the following:

```
runuser - ubuntu -c './panorama.sh'
```